# VS Code throws ModuleNotFoundError despite folder available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyspark, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working on creating a Python/PySpark library using VS Code. My goal is to debug in VS Code and create a `.whl` package to be installed in a Databricks cluster. I face the following situations:

- if I use `from checkenginelib.pysparkdq._constraints._Constraint import _Constraint` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` in VS Code and a module not found error in Databricks
- if I use `from pysparkdq._constraints._Constraint import _Constraint` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` in VS Code but all imports work well in Databricks
- if I use `from _constraints._Constraint import _Constraint` I get no error in VS Code but I get a module not found error in Databricks

[image]

Comment: Only VS Code or also outside?

Comment: If the python file is in the same directory it is sufficient to just import the .py file. In this case then `from validate_df import...`

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are working in `./DATA-QUALITY-ENGINE/check-engine-lib/dqengine/validate_df`. You have to import it the following way:

```
from check-engine-lib.dqengine.validate_df import *
```

That should work. Also you need to create a `\__init__.py`  file to import other files as modules

Comment: I get an syntax error when running ```from check-engine-lib.dqengine.validate_df import *``` due to the ```-```, is that normal?

Comment: Yes, it is. Unfortunately you'll have to change the directory's name to check_engine_lib I suspect

Comment: I followed your sugestion but still got the same error

Comment: Have you added the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: yes, in every folder...

Answer (score 1):

Because your module `dqengine` is not in the top level folder, it is probably not in your `PYTHONPATH` variable, which VSCode has probably added the path to `DATA QUALITY ENGINE`

Either:

- Move it to the top level folder (Data quality engine)
- add the path to `check_engine_lib` to PYTHONPATH.
- Or as @franjefriten says, add an `__init__` to check-engine-lib and do

```
from check-engine-lib.dqengine.validate_df import *
```

Comment: I get an syntax error when running ```from check-engine-lib.dqengine.validate_df import *``` due to the ```-```, is that normal?

Comment: You probably cant have a hyphen in module names, you will have to rename it with underscores or do any of the other points I mentioned

Comment: I followed your sugestion but still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, when the method you need to import is in the same directory as the current file, you only need to import it directly.

```
from validate_df import _Constraint
```